# How to scatter objects on a deformed surface?

Tags: subdivision-surface, shader-nodes, scatter-objects-addon

I am making the surface of the moon and would like to scatter rocks on it. It works with large stones, but small stones do not adapt to the surface and remain "floating" above or below the surface. How should I make them adapt? I use the scatter objects tool.

[image]
You can see the big stones in the right place (but I had to move them up a bit) and the tiny rocks down below the plane.

[image]
I used these nodes to create the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a *Displacement* node, the bumps you're creating are visible in *Rendered* mode but they don't displace the topology for real, that's why when you put some instances on the surface the relief is not taken into account. I don't know if the displacement can be taken into account. What you can do is bake your *Displacement* map and use it in a *Displace* modifier for example, this way the bumps will be real and taken into account.

To bake your texture, create a *Texture > Image Texture* node in your material, click on *New* to create a new image, keep this node selected, plug the whole chain that goes into the *Displacement* node into the *Surface* input of your *Output* node (in my case I just use a *Noise Texture* node but you need to plug the last node of your chain, the *Add* node). Then in the *Render* panel, under *Bake*, choose *Bake Type > Emit* and click on *Bake*. It will make a bitmap picture of the texture you're using as displacement, and you'll be able to use it in a *Displace* modifier (you'll easily find tutos on this modifier).

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a beginner, but what does "bake map" mean? And how can I add it to the displacement modifier?

Comment: I've edited, I hope it's understandable

Comment: I understand a lot more now, but one last thing (I hope), when I click on new, a new window called new image appears, with information about the width, height and color, and I have to confirm it with the ok button, so that I can plug the whole chain in the output . At the same time, this unselects the node image texture. This probably leads to the fact that I have an active color space on the image texture node, while you have it inactive. I'm probably doing something wrong there and that's why it's not working for me.

Comment: Create the new image in the Image Texture, choose the size, then click OK, you don' have to plug this Image Texture node in anything, just keep it selected to make sure that it will be the image that will receive the bake, that's all. Then plug the whole chain you've made into the Output, bake, and you'll see in the Image Editor window (or you can temporarly plug the Image Texture in the Output) that the image you've created has baked the texture created by your node chain. Now you can unplug from the Output, you'll need the bake image in the Displace modifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great help, it works for me now. I would just like to know if there isn't a better way to model the landscape than this complicated way.

Comment: If you already have a b&w image you can directly use it in the Displace modifier, you don't have to bake and so on, I just wanted to explain how to recover your current height map. You could also use procedural textures in the Texture Editor, or directly model the ground (in Sculpt mode for example)